# Why is "will not" contracted as "won't"?

Tags: contractions, modal-verbs, negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “won't” a contraction of?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/what-is-wont-a-contraction-of)

The [Why is "cannot" spelled as one word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4510/1720) post brought back another oddity I noticed when learning English. The contraction *won't* seems to break a common pattern in similar contractions:

- *cannot* => *can't*
- *do not* => *don't*
- *should not* => *shouldn't*
- *would not* => *wouldn't*

In these examples, the *o* sound in *not* is dropped and the letter *o* (*no* in the case of *cannot*) is replaced with an apostrophe.

However, *will not* => *won't* drops *ill* from *will* and replaces it with the *o* from *not*. This contraction is probably derived from shifts in speech rather than writing. How did the contraction *won't* emerge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The building pattern you are proposing is not what happened. As you can see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/what-is-wont-a-contraction-of/4523#4523), *will not* was built from *woll + not*, which assimilated to *wonnot* and then to *won't*.

The use of *woll* comes from the Proto-Indo-European stem *wel-* or *wol-*, refelcted still in the German verb *wollen*: *to will, desire, wish*.

Comment: your mention of the word "woll" reminded me of the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy "wioll haven be" http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~param/quotes/guide.html